# Flutter timer doesn't work when changed from milliseconds to seconds

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

When I change the Duration from milliseconds to seconds the app doesn't load correctly. I get no error in the debug, no logs, nothing, but the app simply doesn't respond to user interaction anymore, it's totally delayed. With milliseconds everything is normal again.

```
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: thisMaxSeconds), (timer) {
              code...
        }
```

Comment: Please share a bit more of the code here. There is not enough information to provide a solution. Is `thisMaxSeconds` possibly 0?

Answer (score 0):

May I know the value passed in the second (`thisMaxSeconds`) parameter of the Duration? If it's too high then periodic `code` execution will be delayed.

Comment: thisMaxSeconds is initially passed as 60, but I don't understand why it works as milli and not as seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause here is that the `thisMaxSeconds` variable is set to 0. This causes the loop to run as quickly as possible, blocking UI interaction and updates.

Paste the following into [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/) to play around.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 0), (timer) {
    print('Tick: ${timer.tick}');
    if(timer.tick == 5){
      print('Done');
      timer.cancel();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: it's initially passed as 60.